Have 2 windows that I need to replace - can't open to measure, but have jamb sizing - How to measure for replacement using window frame/case?
So I have 2 different windows that I need to replace. Since both windows are in unfinished attic spaces I was able to do the measuring from the frame. Unfortunately I can't open them at the moment (they're both single pane, super old, and one of the two has a crack in the glass across the width of one of the parts). The sizes, including the 5/8" thick-per side frame, the measurements for window 1 are:
Width from top to bottom: 29 1/2", 29 1/2", 29 1/4"
Height was 43" for each of the 3 measurements left - right.
Window 2's measurements were all even for each of the 3 sets of measurements for both width and height: 26" x 35 1/4".
When going to order new replacement windows, what sizing should I be getting for each?
Thanks in advance!

Do you intend to get "replacement windows that fit inside the old frame" (so you have a smaller window) or do you intend to remove the old frames and install "new construction" type windows in the rough opening to replace the old ones?

I'm most likely removing the old frames - I just need to know ROUGHLY what size, based on the current size, I should be looking at, or how I should account for the correct measurement when ordering the new windows.

Sizing depends on the manufacturer of the window.
The important measurement is the rough opening size. That is the size of the framing opening for the window. (not the size of the window frame.) If there is trim around the windows on the inside, remove it to get an accurate measurement of the rough opening.
Your need to get the rough opening size and find windows made to fit that opening.  For example you may have a rough opening of 30 inches by 44 inches.
different manufacturers may have a window sized as 30/42 and they will have frame measurements of 29 1/4 by 41 1/2.  so they will fit your rough opening. Others may measure 29 3/8 by 41 1/4, but it will still fit the rough opening.
One manufacturer may not have a size to fit the opening properly, others may.
In any case be prepared to shim the new window as it should not fit the rough opening tightly. Any swelling or movement of the wood could cause the frame of the window to warp or bow and the window can be hard to open or even crack. It is good to have a minimum of 1/4 inch gap between the frame and rough opening.

+1 to “remove the trim”. And use a level to ensure that the opening is level and plumb. If not, use the shortest numbers. (If, for example, the opening is parallelogram’d leaning to the right, measure from the top left to a plumb line on the right.)

So then as long as the rough opening size of the new/replacement windows is close to the size of the existing window + frame, I'm good? I assume I'd want to get as close to the rough opening as I can so as to not need to shim too much.

@helixdnb, yes .  The new window will be sized as glass AND frame and you should be able to get the recommended rough opening for that window.....OR just take your rough opening sizes to the vendor and they will tell you what will fit.

Price is Right rules: close but not over. It’s true that you don’t want a ton of gap between your RO and the window unit, but if you cut it too close, it might go bad. (Voice of experience, here.) As @RMDman said, take an accurate RO size to the vendor and let them size the window for you. (My opinion is that you’ll want 1/2” all around, but that varies.)
